# Org loads onto setup home rather than Home tab

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have the 'default home page' set to custom lightning page that I set using the lightning app builder. Yet my developer org loads onto the setup home. How can I make this org load on the actual home tab?

Comment: Did you activate that default home page?
If yes did you activate that default home page for all profiles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a per-user setting each user can configure to their liking. Go to My Setup, Display & Layout, Customize My Pages. There, you can select the default tab to see when you log in, and check a box to change your default landing page to Setup. Uncheck the box and save your change, and when you next log in, you'll land on your preferred landing tab.

Comment: Does anyone know if this can be done via the metadata api?

Comment: @DanielFuller No, because it's not metadata in that sense. There are a number of settings in Personal Settings that have no corresponding field on the user object and cannot be set by any API.

Answer (score 1):

From Quick Find Box Search for  `App Manager`-->Select your App and Click `edit` you will get a screen like below Image

[image]

Select Home and move to Top. Then Click Done.

Then Assign to Profiles you Required.

For Safe Side Check **Home Tab** **Default On** in Profiles.